# How can I show openslide.deepzoom.DeepZoomGenerator in my PyQt5 interface?

Tags: python, pyqt, openslide

I need to show openslide.deepzoom.DeepZoomGenerator in PyQt5. There are examples of showing DeepZoomGenerator in Flask web-interface. You can check them out here: https://github.com/openslide/openslide-python/tree/master/examples/deepzoom . I need to do something like deepzoom_server.py only with PyQt5 and not Flask. Another example: https://openslide.org/demo/ . How would I integrate DeepZoomGenerator in the code below?

I've read openslide-docs a couple of times. There's no information on my problem. Also I tried traditional googling.

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QWidget, QApplication, QPushButton, QHBoxLayout, QLabel
from PyQt5 import QtGui

import sys


class Window(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.title = "PyQt5 OpenSlide"
        self.left = 500
        self.top = 200
        self.width = 400
        self.height = 100

        self.init_window()

    def init_window(self):
        self.setWindowTitle(self.title)
        self.setGeometry(self.left, self.top, self.width, self.height)

        self.create_layout()

        self.show()

    def create_layout(self):
        pass


if __name__ == "__main__":
    App = QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = Window()
    sys.exit(App.exec())
```

I expect something like deepzoom_server.py